# R data.table - quick comparison of strings

Tags: r, data.table, grepl

I would like to find a fast solution to the following problem. 
The example is very small, real data big and speed is an important factor.

I have two vectors of strings, currently in data.tables but this not so important. I need to find frequency of occurrences of strings from one vector in the second one and keep these results.

Example

```
library(data.table)

dt1<-data.table(c("first","second","third"),c(0,0,0))
dt2<-data.table(c("first and second","third and fifth","second and no else","first and second and third"))
```

Now, for every item in dt1 I need to find in how many items from dt2 it is contained and save the final frequencies to the second column of dt1.
The task itself is not difficult. I have, however, not managed to find reasonably quick solution.

The solution I have now is this:

```
pm<-proc.time()
for (l in 1:dim(dt2)[1]) {
    for (k in 1:dim(dt1)[1]) set(dt1,k,2L,dt1[k,V2]+as.integer(grepl(dt1[k,V1],dt2[l,V1])))
}
proc.time() - pm
```

Real data are very large and this is pretty slow, on my PC even this larger version takes 2 seconds

```
dt1<-data.table(rep(c("first","second","third"),10),rep(c(0,0,0),10))
dt2<-data.table(rep(c("first and second","third and fifth","second and no else","first and second and third"),10))

pm<-proc.time()
for (l in 1:dim(dt2)[1]) {
    for (k in 1:dim(dt1)[1]) set(dt1,k,2L,dt1[k,V2]+as.integer(grepl(dt1[k,V1],dt2[l,V1])))
}
proc.time() - pm

   user  system elapsed 
   1.93    0.06    2.06
```

Do I miss a better solution to this - I would say quite simple - task?
Actually it is so simple that I am sure that it must be a duplicate, but I have not managed to find it here or anything equivalent.

Cross merging of the data.tables is not possible due to memory problems (in the real situation).
Thank you.

Comment: how big is your actual data?

Comment: 1000+ in both tables and some of the strings are quite long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt1[, V2 := sapply(V1, function(x) sum(grepl(x, dt2$V1)))]
```

Also you probably can use fixed string matching for speed.
In that case you can use `stri_detect_fixed` from `stringi` package:

```
dt1[, V2 := sapply(V1, function(x) sum(stri_detect_fixed(dt2$V1, x)))]
```

Comment: Incredible speed. Thanks!